# this.$store is undefined in Vue3 with Vuex4 store and router

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to set up a Vue3 app with a Vuex4 store but I can't seem to get the store accessible in any component, always some undefined error.  I've tried many other solutions but seem to keep running in circles when I go to finally test so I feel like this is something simple I'm missing.

main.ts:

```
import App from "./App.vue";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import createRouter from "@/router"
import createStore from "@/store"

const app = createApp(App);
const store = createStore();
const router = createRouter(app, store);
app
  .use(store)
  .use(router);

router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app');
});
```

router/index.ts:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router"
import AppLayout from '../layouts/AppLayout.vue'
import { App } from 'vue';

export default function (app: App, store: any) {
  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: AppLayout,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: () => import('../views/Dashboard.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'accounts',
          component: () => import('../views/Accounts.vue'),
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
  const router = createRouter({ 
    routes,
    history: createWebHistory()
  })

  return router
}
```

store/index.ts:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex"

const store = {
  state: () => ({
    foo: "bar",
  })
}

export default function () {
  return createStore(store)
}
```

views/Dashboard.vue

```
<script>
// ??? all some variation of undefined
// console.log(this.$store)
// console.log(this.store)
// console.log(store)

// import { useStore } from "vuex";
// const store = useStore();
// console.log(store)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to debug like this?

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$store);
  },
};
</script>
```

Your setup seems ok, but then at components you should be able to get store from inside `export default` at Options API. If using Composition then you need to do this

```js
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I finally got it to log to the console with your first code block.